# Python in conda environment is not conda python

Tags: python, conda

Python command in my Conda environment is not detected as Conda Python interpreter. 
After I activate Conda environment and command Python, it is still calling my system python.

I found this issue cuz I installed all the packages I need for a project and when I run the code it couldn't find the module.

When I check

```
python --version
Python 3.6.4
```

Which should be python 3.7.3 in my Anaconda3

also when I check the location of python

```
which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

this one is not under anaconda directory.
I check that anaconda3 folder and there were python3 and python3.7.

```
/anaconda3/bin/python3.7
python3            python3.7          python3.7m
python3-config     python3.7-config   python3.7m-config
```

Is there any way to solve the problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know [how to configure your PATH variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059/214420)?

Comment: @NiayeshIsky in FAQ, they said "Install Anaconda or Miniconda normally. There is no need to set the PYTHONPATH environment variable." but should I export PYTHONPATH?

Comment: The PATH variable is different from the PYTHONPATH variable. You should learn about [what the PATH is and how to use it](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux). Once you understand that, you will know how to solve your problem.

Comment: @NiayeshIsky If you are mentioning PATH for anaconda3, I already check it in my bash_profile and bashrc

Comment: When you run `echo $PATH`, you should see the path to your Anaconda distribution of Python earlier than `/usr/bin`. If it appears later, `/usr/bin/python` will still be used because it will be found first, since the PATH is obeyed in order. Also, I hope you actually read the article I linked, since you _must_ understand how to use the PATH if you're using a Unix-based OS.

Comment: Solved: [this link](https://github.com/landlab/landlab/wiki/Correcting-Install-Paths) helped me a lot. In my case, I had a `.profile` file other than `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score -1):

Solved: [this link](https://github.com/landlab/landlab/wiki/Correcting-Install-Paths) helped me a lot.

I've already added PATH to my bash files when I asked the question.

In my case, I had a `.profile` file other than `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`.